# Slick Carousel with Elevate Zoom

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have a carousel(slick.js) for product images and i'm trying to implement zoom on these images however no matter which image is active in the slick carousel I only see the last image in the carousel in the zoom container, here is my code.

HTML

```
<ul class="image-carousel">
    <li>
        <img src="/image1.png" data-zoom-image="/image1-large.jpg" class="zoom">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/image2.png" data-zoom-image="/image2-large.jpg" class="zoom">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/image3.png" data-zoom-image="/image3-large.jpg" class="zoom">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/image4.png" data-zoom-image="/image4-large.jpg" class="zoom">
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(".image-carousel").slick();
$(".zoom").elevateZoom();
```

Comment: Are you open to using other jQuery plugins for the carousel and zoom?

Answer (score 1):

When changed,

```
$('#slider-for').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
   var img = $(slick.$slides[nextSlide]).find("img");
   $('.zoomWindowContainer,.zoomContainer').remove();
   $(img).elevateZoom();
});
```

Page Loaded

```
$('#slider-for .slick-current img').elevateZoom();
```

This is the correct one. You can try.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code as it given below.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
   Layout = null;
 }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Scripts/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>

<ul class="image-carousel">
    <li>
        <img id="zoom_01" class="zoom" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="zoom" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="zoom" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image4.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".image-carousel").slick();
        $(".zoom").elevateZoom();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. All that happens now is the elevateZoom fires when you click an images instead of firing on page load.

Comment: can you give me the link from where you have picked this plugin.